# Error in creating procedure Oracle SQL

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a procedure that deletes the *employee* with the greatest *salary*. I have this code:

```
create or replace procedure DelMostExpensive
as
begin
delete from hr.Employees where 
hr.Employees.EmpName=
(select EmpName from hr.Employees where 
salary = (select max(salary) from hr.Employees))
and hr.Employees.birthDate=
(select birthDate from hr.Employees where 
salary = (select max(salary) from hr.Employees));
end;
```

But I get these errors:
**Error(4,1): PL/SQL: SQL statement ignored.
Error(4,16): PL/SQL: Ora-00942 table or view does not exist.**
How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at line 4:

`delete from hr.Almalmazott2 where`

Do you know what table you're trying to delete from? This looks like a table column.

Comment: nope and sorry I forgot to translate. hr is a schema, hr.Employees is a table itself.

Comment: Ok, are you able to `desc fr.Employees` ?

Comment: I am. I see the name, salary, job, whatnots.